# How to write a secret to azure key vault from Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I have created a Key Vault in Azure DevOps using ARM and I now want to write a secret to it within the same pipeline.

I created an Azure PowerShell task with the following inline PowerShell:

```
$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString $(Secret) -AsPlainText -Force
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $(VaultName) -Name $(SecretName) -SecretValue (ConvertTo-SecureString $(Secret) -AsPlainText -Force)
```

The key vault gets created fine, but I get the following error when trying to write the secret:

`[error]Access denied`

If I run `Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret` on my local machine it works fine.

**EDIT**

Here are some screenshots of what I've done. In Azure DevOps I created a Service Connection and verified it:

[image]

Here's what my Azure PowerShell task looks like to write the secret to the vault:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Key Vault permissions:

[image]

[image]

Do I need a separate Service Principal or do I need to create an App Registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you gave rights to the wrong entity. To find the proper entity do this.

Click `Manage` link in the `Azure Subscription` field, it will navigate you to a new blade. Click `Manage Service Principal` there. It will take you to the application page in Azure AD. After that you can copy name under `Managed application in local directory` field and use that name to grant it Key Vault permissions.

Comment: That was it! I also added the objectId to my ARM template parameters so when the key vault is deployed, Azure DevOps gets access to write secrets. All good.

Answer (score 2):

Check your permissions for the service connection to ARM and permissions in your vault. Steps to check are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=vsts

Comment: I did that and have edited my question to show the screenshots. It still is not working. Is there anything else I need to do with the Service Connection?