# update variable group from azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to update a variable in a variable group using `az pipelines` cli from the pipeline, I have created a PAT and passed on to the pipeline its working fine. but I use the default one such as `$(System.AccessToken)` its able to list the variable from the variable group but unable to update the variable group.
Its saying

> ERROR: You do not have permissions to perform this operation on the
> variable group. A variable group Administrator should add you to the
> Administrator role.
> ##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1

after some search I found that I need to add Project Collection Build Service (**name**) as the administrator in the variable group and try again. I have added that but still I am getting the same error. any suggestions?

I am using classic pipeline, here is the exported task from the pipeline.

```
steps
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'sc'
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     az extension add --name azure-devops
     az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id id --org "orgname" --project "projectname"
     az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id id --name apim-service-name --value $(str_tf_module_containername) --org "orgname" --project "projectname"
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Comment: Under which identity are you running the az commands? I can see you're using a service connection. Can you try to add an `az account show` and check the logs to see whether the account/identity has the required Administrator permissions for the variable group?

Comment: Adding the Project Collection Build Service as an **Administrator** helped me get past the error. Is this still an issue?

Comment: yes, I cant use the system.accesstoken, I had to use the my own PAT to get this done for now.

Comment: System.Accesstoken is a PAT token generated for the service identity “Project Collection Build Service (account)”. This token is valid for 48 hours.

Comment: @threeleggedrabbit Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well..

Comment: As mentioned above, I had to use the my own PAT to get this done for now.

Answer (score 5):

This works well:

```yaml
steps
- pwsh: |
     az extension add --name azure-devops
     az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id id --org "orgname" --project "projectname"
     az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id id --name apim-service-name --value $(str_tf_module_containername) --org "orgname" --project "projectname"
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

but you need to give`Project Collection Build Service (account)` Administrator permission on give variable group:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you define your variable group based on an [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault), then it is quite easy for your pipeline to save a new value to the vault with just a line or two of powershell.

See this question and answer for an example: [How to write a secret to azure key vault from Azure DevOps pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910591/how-to-write-a-secret-to-azure-key-vault-from-azure-devops-pipeline)